# No Available Columns for OTRS 4 Open Tickets Widget in the Dashboard

Tags: widget, dashboard, otrs

After upgrading from 3.2.17 all the way to 4.0.7 (and rewriting our customizations for the new version) it would seem there are columns missing in the open tickets widget and the widget has no columns available within the widget settings.

[image: Open Tickets Settings]

The new tickets widget settings have no problem populating columns.

[image: New Tickets Settings]

Version 3.2.17 displayed

[image: Open Tickets Display 3.2.17]

While version 4.0.7 is displaying

[image: Open Tickets Display 4.0.7]

Anyone have any thoughts where the issue may lie?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, that your "Customizations" have broken the Config XML file.

Take a look at config option  DashboardBackend###0110-TicketOpen and compare it to TicketNew option just above it.

There is a list of available/Default columns. Check if they are there!
[OTRS TicketOpen Default Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBcWH.png)

In case it does not help, please enlist the System Log content just after browsing the dashboard and maybe /var/log/httpd/error_log content as well for any system errors

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for the direction. When I get back to work on Monday I will check those out. I inherited a customized system that was on 3.2 and would really like to get it up to a supported version.

Comment: I just got up with another thought. 
Have you properly migrated from dtl templating mechanism ( OTRS v.3 ) to .tt templating mechanism ( OTRS v.4 ), as there are significant changes especially in templating, and if the Open ticket widget was modifyed, then it might crash just at presentation layer

Comment: It is in the ZZZAuto.pm generated config file. I copied over this autogenerated file. The OTRS documentation says to copy this file. Is there any reason to keep it?

Comment: No, this is definitely wrong!!!

ZZZAuto NEVER should be copied over to another system! It is generated every time you make any changes into SysConfig. To properly transfer settings between your system you should go to old system press Export Config and in new system import this generated file!

Comment: Why in the world does the OTRS maintainers put it in their documentation to copy it over? It seems as though someone really dropped the ball on the documentation. Using the import/export makes sense. I will do that to make sure the settings are in sync.